# Issue while installing SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-scan

I tried to install SonarQube on my laptop. But when I run the `StartSonar.bat` file, I get the following output:

```
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2016.10.15 04:04:00 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory D:\sonarqube-5.6.3\temp
jvm 1    | 2016.10.15 04:04:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java 
jvm 1    | 2016.10.15 04:04:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
jvm 1    | 2016.10.15 04:04:23 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped

wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I checked the logs, but I can't find anything. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Can you attach logs/sonar.log please ?

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zsx5gUb2)

Comment: You should delete the files and directories stored in D:\sonarqube-5.6.3\data then try again.

Comment: Still same :/ I delete whole file, unzip new one, delete data file and try but still same. :(

Comment: It may occur if you have another SonarQube with default embedded database running on the same box. Is it your case ?

Comment: No, this is my first try. I never used before.

Can you write steps of installation for me ? (Dummy instructions)

It'll be useful. I'll start from begining

Comment: You can find information at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately i try to do 2 minutes guide but still same error.

Comment: Just dockerize it. Download docker and install it. That simple :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out that I didn't have the rights to run Sonar in my computer. Had to go and ask someone from IT with administrator rights.

Comment: I can't figure it out why. But easiest way is. Just dockerize it. Download docker and install it. That simple :)

Answer (score 0):

1-Please look into the sonar log not in command line console.

2-Basically this error comes when there is environment variable not set properly.

3-Please check the java version compatibility also.